# How is bromothymol blue synthetised?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

In a classical reaction, phenolphthalein is synthetised from phthalic anhydride and phenol with acid catalyst. When one uses substituted phenols, one obtains similar compounds (e. g. cresolphthalein, thymohlphthalein).

However, some acid-base indicators contain a sulfo- group instead of a carboxy- group of phthaleins. Does that mean that they are synthetised from phenols and the anhydride of o-sulfobenzoic acid? Phthalic anhydride is fairly cheap, but how is o-sulfobenzoic anhydride prepared?

Comment: Phthalic anhydride is prepared industrially by catalytic oxidation of naphthalene or o-xylene over vanadium pentoxide https://thechemco.com/chemical/phthalic-anhydride/

Comment: @Waylander I meant o-sulfobenzoic anhydride, but it wasn't really clear. I edited the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Now a days, sulfonephthaleins can be prepared by reaction of readily available saccharin and the desired plenol compound (Ref.1 & Ref.2). In this method, active reagent, sulfobenzoic anhydride will be prepared *in situ* as depicted in following diagram:

[image: Sulfonephthalein]

In this method, it's described the preparation of phenolsulfonephthalein (Phenol Red). If you use thymol instead of phenol, you will get thymolsulfonephthalein, which can be subsequently brominated by bromine/acetic acid to obtain dibromothymolsulfonephthalein (Bromothymol Blue). This procedure is described in Ref.2.

**References:**

1. V. H. Tillu, D. K. Dumbre, H. B. Borate, R. D. Wakharkar, V. R. Choudhary, "Solvent-Free One-Pot Synthesis of Sulfonephthaleins from Saccharin and Phenols," *Synthetic Communications* **2012**, *42(8)*, 1101-1107 (https://doi.org/10.1080/00397911.2010.535946).
2. B. S. Rao, J. B. Puschett, B. M. Karandikar, K. Matyjaszewski, "Synthesis of Functional Bromothymol Blue Dyes for Surface Attachment to Optical Fibers," *Dyes and Pigments* **1991**, *16(1)*, 27-34 (https://doi.org/10.1016/0143-7208(91)87018-I).

Answer (score 1):

o-Sulfobenzoic Anhydride is prepared by cyclisation of ammonium *o*-sulfobenzoate (itself prepared by cHCl hydrolysis of saccharin) with thionyl chloride in benzene. The Organic Syntheses procedure is here: [Org Syn](http://www.orgsyn.org/demo.aspx?prep=CV1P0495)

[image]

Comment: But is bromothymol blue actually synthetised from sulfobenzoic anhydride?

Comment: This reference may tell you https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/014372089187018I  From the abstract it looks like it is